# confusionMatrix.default(test$Y, prediction) : the data cannot have more levels than the reference in R

Tags: r

I try use automl library to create model

```
library(automl)
itog=read.csv("itog.csv")
str(itog)
itog$X=NULL
itog$Y=as.factor(itog$Y)
set.seed(123)
library(rsample)
library(dplyr)
indexes = createDataPartition(itog$Y, p = .7, list = F)
train = itog[indexes, ]
test = itog[-indexes, ]

amlmodel = automl_train_manual(Xref = subset(train, select = -c(Y),
                               Yref = subset(train, select = c(Y))$Y
                               %>% as.numeric(),
                               hpar = list(learningrate = 0.01,
                                           minibatchsize = 2^2,
                                           numiterations = 60))
prediction = automl_predict(model = amlmodel, X = test[,1:3]) 
prediction = ifelse(prediction > 2.5, 2, ifelse(prediction > 1.5, 2, 1)) %>% as.factor()
caret::confusionMatrix(test$Y, prediction)
```

I checked any topics with this problem(it was many similar), but these advices didn't help me or i maybe wrong use it?

can anybody please explain why this error ocurres?

```
itog=structure(list(r = c(408L, 450L, 667L, 477L, 374L, 260L, 419L, 
441L, 658L, 374L, 333L, 313L, 404L, 432L, 458L, 457L, 286L, 286L, 
259L, 238L, 230L, 214L, 259L, 201L, 232L, 235L, 233L, 252L, 271L, 
259L, 235L, 210L, 206L, 244L, 218L, 211L, 246L, 242L, 217L, 255L, 
277L, 262L, 280L, 278L, 289L, 271L, 236L, 249L, 235L, 248L, 263L, 
217L, 263L, 300L, 242L, 269L, 280L, 301L, 317L, 247L, 218L, 209L, 
237L, 253L), g = c(384L, 418L, 656L, 480L, 397L, 341L, 441L, 
461L, 597L, 422L, 394L, 314L, 433L, 451L, 464L, 406L, 260L, 262L, 
216L, 244L, 230L, 222L, 234L, 242L, 211L, 232L, 231L, 235L, 281L, 
251L, 241L, 194L, 192L, 222L, 234L, 269L, 220L, 221L, 226L, 224L, 
210L, 274L, 272L, 281L, 247L, 264L, 226L, 247L, 254L, 223L, 255L, 
217L, 238L, 260L, 248L, 247L, 272L, 313L, 323L, 254L, 202L, 202L, 
297L, 269L), b = c(372L, 477L, 617L, 495L, 414L, 314L, 430L, 
487L, 623L, 514L, 351L, 343L, 422L, 433L, 449L, 425L, 363L, 326L, 
312L, 308L, 286L, 259L, 243L, 265L, 280L, 298L, 303L, 301L, 359L, 
298L, 295L, 265L, 263L, 298L, 275L, 332L, 303L, 287L, 305L, 285L, 
298L, 339L, 339L, 359L, 300L, 293L, 289L, 277L, 326L, 312L, 311L, 
289L, 317L, 325L, 343L, 332L, 379L, 422L, 415L, 326L, 292L, 257L, 
288L, 306L), Y = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-64L))
```

Comment: In the chained `ifelse` you assign the value `2` twice. Is this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that the chained `ifelse` is wrong when it assigns the value `2` to two levels of `prediction`.

The following code works as expected. It removes unnecessary instructions, it uses `cut`, that returns a factor, and explicitly sets the factor levels.

I don't load nor use package `dplyr` and use the new (R 4.1.0) operator `|>` instead of `magrittr`'s `%>%`.

```
library(automl)
library(rsample)

str(itog)
itog$Y <- factor(itog$Y, levels = 1:3)

set.seed(123)
indexes <- caret::createDataPartition(itog$Y, p = 0.7, list = FALSE)
train <- itog[indexes, ]
test <- itog[-indexes, ]

amlmodel <- automl_train_manual(
  Xref = train[1:3],
  Yref = train$Y |> as.numeric(),
  hpar = list(learningrate = 0.01,
              minibatchsize = 2^2,
              numiterations = 60)
)

prediction <- automl_predict(model = amlmodel, X = test[1:3]) 
prediction <- cut(prediction, breaks = c(-0.1, 1.5, 2.5, Inf), labels = 1:3)
caret::confusionMatrix(test$Y, prediction)
```